# MongoDB ignoring case insensitivity when using @Query

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I am using Mongodb in a Spring Boot application. I am able to filter my database thru the CLI just fine with basic regex filter like `{ 'name': /<something>/i }` but using the same filter with `@Query` like this `@Query("{ 'name': /?0/i }")` ignores the case insensitivity from the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone wondering in the future, I solved this by using `{'name': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'} }` instead of `{ 'name': /?0/i }` in `@Query`